# VBA Index Marco can not auto fill data if the last row of Colum A is blank

Tags: vba, indexing, match, autofill

I am having a issue to auto fill data from another sheet, I am trying to enter "sku" Value in Sheet(Report), then auto fill both "Store name" & "qty" from another Sheet(SOH). However, if the last row of the "store name" (Column A, Report Sheet) = Blank, this Marco will not working properly, otherwise it is working fine. Did I miss something? Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```
Sub Fill_Report()
    Dim d, s As Long
    Dim sQTY As Double
    Dim dws, sws As Worksheet
   
    Set dws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report") 'Destination Sheet
    Set sws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SOH")  'Source Sheet
    
    dlr = dws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    slr = sws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For d = 2 To dlr
        For s = 2 To slr

            ssku = sws.Cells(s, "A:A").Value
            dsku = dws.Cells(d, "B:B").Value
        
            'Index qty from source
            sQTY = Application.IfError(Application.Index(Sheets("SOH").Range("A:Z"), _
                Application.Match(ssku, Sheets("Report").Range("B:B"), 0), 2), 0)
            
            'add title
            dws.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Sotre Name"
            dws.Cells(1, 2).Value = "sku"
            dws.Cells(1, 3).Value = "qty"

            If dsku = ssku Then
        
                dws.Cells(d, "A").Value = "ABC"
                dws.Cells(d, "C").Value = sQTY
                Exit For
            End If
        Next s
    Next d

End Sub
```

[image]
[image]

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collections and Dictionaries are optimized for fast lookups.  Consider using them over Match and Index.

`Range("A1").CurrentRegion` will select the entire range of contiguous cells.

```
Sub Fill_Report()
    Dim Quantities As New Collection
    
    Set Quantities = getSKUQuantity
    
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = wsReport.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns("B").Offset(1)
    
    Dim r As Long
    Dim QTY As Double
    
    For r = r To UBound(Data)
        On Error Resume Next
        QTY = Quantities(Data(r, 1))
        
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            Data(r, 1) = QTY
        Else
            Data(r, 1) = ""
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next
    
    wsReport.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns("C").Offset(1).Value = Data
End Sub

Function getSKUQuantity() As Collection
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = wsSOH.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    Dim Quantities As New Collection
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 2 To UBound(Data)
        On Error Resume Next
        
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            Quantities.Add Data(r, 2), CStr(Data(r, 1))
        Else
            Debug.Print "Duplicate SKU: ", Data(r, 1)
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next
    Set getSKUQuantity = Quantities
    
End Function

Function wsSOH() As Worksheet
    Set wsSOH = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SOH")
End Function

Function wsReport() As Worksheet
    Set wsReport = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Report")
End Function
```